# Need help on Terraform to create app service for Java based app

Tags: terraform, azure-appservice

Need help on Terraform to create app service for Java-based app

I am looking for the below configuration for my java-based app

```
site_config{
  linux_fx_version = "TOMCAT|9.0-jre8"
 }
```

while running with this configuration I am getting the below error:
"**The parameter LinuxFxVersion has an invalid value**."
Any Idea why ??
[image]

Comment: Does Azure expose an API log where you can see the full detail of the API call the UI generates? If so that might tell you the exact value you need.

Comment: does expose the logs defines the value. currently i am not sure but what value i need to passon if expose the logs and what value i need to use if dont exposes the logs?

Comment: The API log (by which I mean Azure's equivalent of AWS cloudtrail) might show what parameter value the GUI method of service creation generates, and that value might also work in Terraform.

Comment: sorry I am not clear about this, could you please give me an example?

Comment: I don't know Azure, but Microsoft lists Monitor as its equivalent service. If Monitor logs can show you the details of the API call that occurs when you create the app service via the browser, then you can try the same value for LinuxFxVersion in Terraform.

Comment: Try to create App Service manually on Azure portal, create empty terraform App Service resource and import created App Service using 'terraform import ...' command. The next run of the 'terraform plan' will show you the exact resource configuration.

Comment: I have already tried .... the import resource gives option as  linux_fx_version = "TOMCAT|9.0-jre8" but when I run this to create app service it throughs an error